# Computer usage only with a valid voucher

Tags: windows

i have a special problem. I own a little cafe with two windows 8 computers. My customers can buy time on this computers. At the moment i manage it with my eyes.

My dream setup would be that the customers comes to me and i give him a code. With this code he can use the computer for 1 hour. After this hour he can buy the next code from me. The pfsense [Captive Portal Vouchers](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Captive_Portal_Vouchers) is exactly what i need with one exception, a customer can use the computer for Games, Word ... he needs the code only when he uses the internet.

Is there any way to do this? I have a pfsense firewall in my cafe.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a homegrown solution, but an acquaintance of mine has used [CyberCafePro](http://www.cybercafepro.com/features.php) with some success. The **software is free**.

I am not an adbot for the software. I just saw your question and recalled the name of the software. That was a few years ago and I know they switched ownership so, I guess, YMMV. You might give it a run if nothing else comes along with your post.